# How is it possible that vpasolve gives empty vector when there are solutions?

Tags: matlab

I have a system of equations containing cosine and sine functions. The unknowns are angles so the range is between 0 and 360 degrees. When I put in these ranges then vpasolve gives back empty vectors when there are solutions. How is it possible that vpasolve does not give back the solutions? And vpasolve gives back the solutions when I narrow the ranges down. But it should find the solutions within a range of at most 90 degrees.

This is my code:

```
clear; close all; clc

% Given parameters
A = [0 0]; % Coordinates of winch

SlingPos = [2   3;
            10  8;
            0  26;
            22 20;
            52 32;]; % Coordinates of the fixed point of the slings

SlingLen = [1;
            2;
            2.5;
            3;
            4]; % Length of the slings

Pwr = [0;
       0;
       0;
       0;
       0;]; % Percent friction in sheave 1

M = 500;  % Mass of load

% Calculate angles and resultant force in the slings
syms(sym('theta',[1 length(SlingLen)])) % Create symbolic variables for the angles theta
syms(sym('T',[1 length(SlingLen)])) % Create symbolic variables for the resultant forces T
syms(sym('phi',[1 length(SlingLen)])) % Create symbolic variables for the angles phi
Fg = M*9.81; % Gravity

Fpull = zeros(length(SlingLen),1);
Fpull(end) = ((100+Pwr(end))/100)*Fg; % Pulling force of the last sheave

% Calculate other pulling forces
for i = length(SlingLen)-1:-1:1
    Fpull(i) = ((100+Pwr(i))/100)*Fpull(i+1);
end

%TEST

[phi1, theta1, T1, phi2, theta2, T2, phi3, theta3, T3, phi4, theta4, T4, phi5, theta5, T5] = vpasolve(...
    -Fpull(1)*cosd(phi1)-T1*cosd(theta1)+Fpull(2)*cosd(phi2)==0,...
    Fpull(1)*sind(phi1)+T1*sind(theta1)-Fpull(2)*sind(phi2)==0,...
    -Fpull(2)*cosd(phi2)-T2*cosd(theta2)+Fpull(3)*cosd(phi3)==0,...
    Fpull(2)*sind(phi2)+T2*sind(theta2)-Fpull(3)*sind(phi3)==0,...
    -Fpull(3)*cosd(phi3)-T3*cosd(theta3)+Fpull(4)*cosd(phi4)==0,...
    Fpull(3)*sind(phi3)+T3*sind(theta3)-Fpull(4)*sind(phi4)==0,...
    -Fpull(4)*cosd(phi4)-T4*cosd(theta4)+Fpull(5)*cosd(phi5)==0,...
    Fpull(4)*sind(phi4)+T4*sind(theta4)-Fpull(5)*sind(phi5)==0,...
    -Fpull(5)*cosd(phi5)-T5*cosd(theta5)==0,...
    Fpull(5)*sind(phi5)+T5*sind(theta5)-Fg==0,...
    A(1,1)+sqrt((abs(A(1,1)-SlingPos(1,1))+SlingLen(1)*cosd(theta1))^2+(abs(A(1,2)-SlingPos(1,2))-SlingLen(1)*sind(theta1))^2)*cosd(phi1)==SlingPos(1,1)+SlingLen(1)*cosd(theta1),...
    SlingPos(1,1)+SlingLen(1)*cosd(theta1)+sqrt((abs(SlingPos(1,1)+SlingLen(1)*cosd(theta1)-SlingPos(2,1))+SlingLen(2)*cosd(theta2))^2+(abs(SlingPos(1,2)-SlingLen(1)*sind(theta1)-SlingPos(2,2))-SlingLen(2)*sind(theta2))^2)*cosd(phi2)==SlingPos(2,1)+SlingLen(2)*cosd(theta2),...
    SlingPos(2,1)+SlingLen(2)*cosd(theta2)+sqrt((abs(SlingPos(2,1)+SlingLen(2)*cosd(theta2)-SlingPos(3,1))-SlingLen(3)*cosd(theta3))^2+(abs(SlingPos(2,2)-SlingLen(2)*sind(theta2)-SlingPos(3,2))-SlingLen(3)*sind(theta3))^2)*cosd(phi3)==SlingPos(3,1)+SlingLen(3)*cosd(theta3),...
    SlingPos(3,1)+SlingLen(3)*cosd(theta3)+sqrt((abs(SlingPos(3,1)+SlingLen(3)*cosd(theta3)-SlingPos(4,1))+SlingLen(4)*cosd(theta4))^2+(abs(SlingPos(3,2)-SlingLen(3)*sind(theta3)-SlingPos(4,2))+SlingLen(4)*sind(theta4))^2)*cosd(phi4)==SlingPos(4,1)+SlingLen(4)*cosd(theta4),...
    SlingPos(4,1)+SlingLen(4)*cosd(theta4)+sqrt((abs(SlingPos(4,1)+SlingLen(4)*cosd(theta4)-SlingPos(5,1))+SlingLen(5)*cosd(theta5))^2+(abs(SlingPos(4,2)-SlingLen(4)*sind(theta4)-SlingPos(5,2))-SlingLen(5)*sind(theta5))^2)*cosd(phi5)==SlingPos(5,1)+SlingLen(5)*cosd(theta5),...
    [phi1,theta1,T1,phi2,theta2,T2,phi3,theta3,T3,phi4,theta4,T4,phi5,theta5,T5],...
    [0 360;0 360;-inf inf;0 360;0 360;-inf inf;0 360;0 360;-inf inf;0 360;0 360;-inf inf;0 360;0 360;-inf inf]);


PosSheave1 = [double(SlingPos(1,1)+SlingLen(1)*cosd(theta1)); double(SlingPos(1,2)-SlingLen(1)*sind(theta1))]
PosSheave2 = [double(SlingPos(2,1)+SlingLen(2)*cosd(theta2)); double(SlingPos(2,2)-SlingLen(2)*sind(theta2))]
PosSheave3 = [double(SlingPos(3,1)+SlingLen(3)*cosd(theta3)); double(SlingPos(3,2)-SlingLen(3)*sind(theta3))]
PosSheave4 = [double(SlingPos(4,1)+SlingLen(4)*cosd(theta4)); double(SlingPos(4,2)-SlingLen(4)*sind(theta4))]
PosSheave5 = [double(SlingPos(5,1)+SlingLen(5)*cosd(theta5)); double(SlingPos(5,2)-SlingLen(5)*sind(theta5))]
```

What I tried is changing the ranges in vpasolve.

Comment: Please [add code and example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of what you have done so far.